# How do I reimburse the gas fee (in ether) to the signer using the safe-core-sdk?

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

I thought reimbursing the signer who is executing the transaction in ether from the safe's ether would be as simple as adding in that refundReceiver param but what I am missing? Thanks!

```
const txOptions = {
    gasPrice: 1000000000,
    gasLimit: 1000000000,
    refundReceiver: signer.address,
  };
  const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction(
    multiSendTx,
    txOptions
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

It is important here what type your `multiSendTx` is. If it is a single transaction the `options` will be ignored, only if it is an array the `options` are applied. For a single transaction you would have to set these values directly on the transaction.

This definition can be seen in the function signature: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/safe-core-sdk/src/Safe.ts#L257-L261

On another note, the parameter you have to set are `safeTxGas`, `gasPrice` and `refundReceiver`. The complete available options are defined here: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/safe-core-sdk/src/utils/transactions/types.ts#L7